# Eclipse CDT+Spresense SDKでデバッグする際に、必要な機材と設定

Tags: spresense

Ubuntu16.04LTS上の、Spresense SDKとEclipse CDTを使い、デバッグと考えています。接続するためのハードウェアの選定と設定にて困っています。

－－－

**▼1：CMSIS-DAPを使うためのハードウェア**
CMSIS-DAPを利用する場合、CN1の先の参考ハードウェア構成を教えていただけたら嬉しいです。半田不良も心配なので、実績のある機材で試したいと考えいます。

[image: CN1コネクタの先をどうすべきでしょうか？]

－－－

**▼2：j-link EDU miniで接続できない(?)**
デバッグ用のプローブとして、[j-Link EDU mini](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/j-link-edu-mini/)を購入してみました。[spresense-opencd](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-openocd)をダウンロードし、接続しようと試みましたが失敗しているように見えます。お時間のある時にアドバイス頂けたら嬉しいです。

**〇 UARTは以下のようにデバッグモードに入っているようです。**

```
Welcome to minicom 2.7

OPTIONS: I18n
Compiled on Nov 15 2018, 20:18:47.
Port /dev/ttyUSB0, 08:41:22

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

Waiting for debugger connection..
```

**〇 J-Linkのコンソール出力**

```
$ cd ~/spresense-openocd/tcl
$ ls interface/jlink.cfg
interface/jlink.cfg
$ ls target/cxd5602_adsp0.cfg
target/cxd5602_adsp0.cfg
$ sudo dmesg
[  333.084620] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  335.218189] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci-pci
[  335.541064] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1366, idProduct=0101
[  335.541067] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  335.541069] usb 1-3: Product: J-Link
[  335.541071] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: SEGGER
[  335.541072] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 000801007240

$ openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg -f target/cxd5602_adsp0.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0-spresense-ge19554e (2019-02-16-20:39)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "jtag". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
Info : No device selected, using first device.
Info : J-Link EDU Mini V1 compiled Jan  7 2019 14:01:42
Info : Hardware version: 1.00
Info : VTarget = 3.294 V
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all ones
Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: spritzer.cpu: IR capture error; saw 0x0f not 0x01
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Error: Invalid ACK (7) in DAP response
Error: JTAG-DP STICKY ERROR
Error: Invalid ACK (7) in DAP response
Error: JTAG-DP STICKY ERROR
...
Error: Invalid ACK (7) in DAP response
Error: JTAG-DP STICKY ERROR
Error: Invalid ACK (7) in DAP response
Error: JTAG-DP STICKY ERROR
Error: Could not initialize the debug port
```

[image: Spresense SDKとj-Link EDU miniの接続]

[image: Eclipseに出力されるエラー]

**▽補足**
Spresense SDK デベロッパーガイドの[10.1.4. Spresense ボードの設定](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/nuttx-developer-guide#_spresense_%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)の「デバッグ設定」節で *gdb-arm-none-eabi* を指定する記述がありましたが、Web上（2019/2/16現在）の手順ではインストールされていませんでした。以下の手順を追加しています。

```
sudo apt install gdb-arm-none-eabi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もう、ご存知かもしれませんが、公式サイトに、

[https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/nuttx-developer-guide#_ハードウェア](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/nuttx-developer-guide#_%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2)

---

10.1.1. ハードウェア

•CMSIS-DAP 準拠デバッグアダプタ (ICE)

◦Keil ULINK2 (http://www.keil.com/arm/ulink2/)
◦NXP LPC-Link2 (https://www.nxp.com/jp/support/developer-resources/software-development-tools/lpc-developer-resources-/lpc-microcontroller-utilities/lpc-link2:OM13054?lang=jp&lang_cd=jp&)

•SWD connector

---

という、記述が更新されていました。

SWDに関しては、

https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/hardware-documentation#_jtag%E3%83%87%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AC%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95

に記載があるようです。

日本コネクトのものは、つながりました。

Comment: 確認が大変遅くなりまして失礼いたしました。お忙しい中情報頂き、誠にありがとうございます！早速こちらで試してみます。